# How to debug signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, sigabrt

I have been learning Swift for a while and signal SIGABRT has occurred quite randomly several times. I've tried some tutorials online but it didn't seem working all the time.

This time I was trying to set up a To Do List with two view controllers. One has a tableview and this other has a textfield to add new items. The followings are the code lines for both. Hope someone could help me solve the puzzle.

```
import UIKit

var toDoList = [String]()

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var toDoListTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return toDoList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell =  UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}


import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var newItem: UITextField!
    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {
        toDoList.append(newItem.text)
        newItem.text = ""  
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have received this error when I accidentally renamed an outlet without updating the connection. Is it possible you made this error?